# Как войти в учетную запись в терминале на мак

Tags: python, консоль, pygame, mac

[image]
терминал не принимает никакие команды,как войти в свою учетную запись,чтобы установить через терминал pygame?

Comment: проблема решилась.Установил pygame, но в пайчарме когда захожу в терминал и пишу import pygame пишет :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python'